# Child Vf pages styling not respected when included in parent vf page

Tags: visualforce, css, pdf, style, include

Here's the scenario:

1. We have 1 parent Vf page rendered as advanced_pdf.
2. We have multiple child VF pages conditionally rendered on opportunity record type, each one has their attribute renderedAs = advanced_pdf with their own  section. The child pages are included in the parent page using apex:include
3. Each chid Vf page renders with the right style as pdf when called out individually.
4. When navigating to the parent page, the child pages render as a single pdf (as expected) but without the right style.

In order to fix the styling, I have already unsuccessfully tried:

1. Leaving parent with renderAs="advanced_pdf" and removing that attribute from child pages.
2. Leaving both, parent and children pages with renderAs="advanced_pdf"
3. Leaving children pages with renderAs="advanced_pdf" and removing it from the parent.
4. Copying the  section of one of the child pages into the parent one and the style is still not respected.

Answer (score 0):

This was solved by copying the child pages Style tag and putting them together into a single Style tag in the parent page.

Another piece that was missing in the parent page was the Link and Script tags in the parent page header to refer to bootstrap and jquery.